# Why .text('ssss') does not change the text of the element in this success call-back of jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, text, callback

I call a page method with a jquery ajax. I can confirm the success method is called as some alerts are working.

But I cannot understand why -eventhough I can alert the right content by checking the .text()- I am not able to change the text of the element here (this block is part of a the success method):

```
var anchorStatus = $('a.quick-update[data-id=' + jsObject.paymentId + ']');

alert(anchorStatus.text()); // alerts a text :'Hello world!'
anchorStatus.text('sssss');  // but it does not change the text to 'ssss' after this call
```

Can you advice?

---

p.S : It was my bad; the page is refreshed and overrides my changes on the UI. I had to prevent default behaviour of one button.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with the code you've written. It should work. So you need to post something closer to the actual code you're using.

Comment: You are right. It was my bad; the page is refreshed and overrides my changes on the UI. I had to prevent default behaviour of one button.